# jQuery ajax load content of a div on another page does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Isn't the jQuery's ajax support the loading of a content from another page? I am fine by using the `.load`, but just curious why?

For example:

```
var ajaxModal = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'ajax-modal'
    }),
    $data = $(link).data(),
    options = {
      url: $(link).prop('href') + ' ' + $data.target
    };

ajaxModal.load(options.url, function() {
    ajaxModal.appendTo('body').show(); // works
});

$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
    ajaxModal.html(data).appendTo('body').show(); // doesn't work
});
```

Comment: What is `ajaxModal`?

Comment: Just a div where the contents are appended.

Comment: Did you debug it? Does `done` callback even get called?

Comment: Yes, it does, but it loads whole page, not the actual div I am requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

If you really want to use ajax in your case you can use something like:

```
$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
    var DivYouWant = $("#DivYouWant", data);
    ajaxModal.html(DivYouWant).appendTo('body').show(); // does work
});
```